# Which string matching language is this?

Tags: visual-studio, continuous-integration, string-matching, azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio Online, but I imagine this is a fairly generic Microsoft tooling thing.  Specifically, while editing a specific build definition's test step

[image: Edit Visual Studio Test]

you can identify the paths containing test assemblies

[image: What is <code>**\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**</code>?]

but I don't recognize the matching string `**\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**`.

**What kind of string matching language is used here and where can I learn more about it?  Is it Microsoft specific?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is MsBuild pattern matching

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms171453.aspx#BKMK_Wildcards

> The ? wildcard character matches a single character.
>   The * wildcard
>   character matches zero or more characters.
>   The ** wildcard
>   character sequence matches a partial path.

Semicolon is a list separator character

Comment: Thanks!  And what about the semicolon, colon, and hyphen? (`;`, `:`, `-` in the string `**\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**`)

Comment: Semicolon is list separator. But have to admit I'm not sure about the the others. I expect colon is volume identifier and maybe hyphen is an exclude flag - but I'm not 100% on that and can't find any documentation to confirm this.

Comment: @kdbanman, AlexS is correct that hyphen is an exclude flag. Please check my reply for the details.

Comment: That makes sense - the `-:` character pair is an exclusion modifier if used before a path.  Are there other modifiers? Or other legal characters not in that particular example?

Answer (score 0):

If you click the exclamation mark, you will check that `**\*test*.dll;-:**\obj\**` means for all dlls with test in name while excluding files in any sub-directory named obj.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I saw that exclamation mark, but what I really want to know is which matching/expansion language that is so that I can learn to use it properly.  Just a single example doesn't help very much.